# exception in JDBC when result returned from SQL query - before start or a result set

Tags: java, mysql

Trying to execute a basic query to MySQL database to check if a user exists in the DB.
after receiving back the result I got an `SQLException` - `"Before start of result set"`

```
private static final String IS_EXISTS = "SELECT count(*) FROM `couponDB`.`companies` WHERE email=? AND password=?";

try {
            connection = ConnectionPool.getInstance().getConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(IS_EXISTS);
            statement.setString(1, email);
            statement.setString(2, password);
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
            return (resultSet.getInt(1) > 0);
        } catch (InterruptedException | SQLException err) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        } finally {
            ConnectionPool.getInstance().returnConnection(connection);
        }
        return false;
```

this works fine but I'm getting the error `Before start of result set`

I understand you need to call the next result by `resultSet.next()`
So I've tried this code

```
private static final String IS_EXISTS = "SELECT * FROM `couponDB`.`companies` WHERE email=? AND password=?";

boolean isExist = false;

        try {
            connection = ConnectionPool.getInstance().getConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(IS_EXISTS);
            statement.setString(1, email);
            statement.setString(2, password);
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

           while ( resultSet.next()) {
               isExist = resultSet.getObject(1, Boolean.class);
           }
        } catch (InterruptedException | SQLException err) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }
        return isExist;
```

Still getting an `SQLExecption` with the massage `Before start of result set`

Comment: Can you please share the stack trace ?

Comment: So why did you change from `count(*)` to `*` ?

Comment: I m curious as to why the second code still has the before start of result set error. Did you save the new code before running it?

Comment: Yes, it used actually fixed the issue, the error massage was from another method that run that didn't used the rs.next() my mistake.